# Redux | How do I properly connect to the redux store

Tags: react-native, redux

I got my redux store to work but only if I import the store in the action creator file and call `store.dispatch()` from the action creator. Apparently calling `store.dispatch()` isn't a good practice and if I connect the function properly to the store, then I can just call `dispatch()` instead of `store.dispatch()`. That said, when I tried to just use `dispatch()`, I got the error: "Can't find variable: dispatch".

My best guess is that my issue is that I'm not using Redux's connect() function properly at the bottom of this code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'; 
import { signup } from '../../actions/authAction'

const ApprovedScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')  

  return (
    <View>
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.textInput}
            value={email}
            onChangeText={text=>setEmail(text)}
        />
        <TextInput 
            value={password}
            onChangeText={text=>setPassword(text)}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>signup({email, password})}>
          <Text>Create An Account</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default connect(null, { signup })(ApprovedScreen)
```

And here's the { signup } function code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { LOG_IN } from './types'

export function signup ({email, password}) {
    console.log('singup function ran')
        axios
        .post('https://MYAPI.com/signup', {email, password})
        .then(response => dispatch({
            type: LOG_IN,
            payload: response.data.token
        }))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using redux-thunk, the action needs to return another function, which takes `dispatch` as an argument:

```
export function signup({ email,  password}) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .post('https://MYAPI.com/signup', {
        email,
        password
      })
      .then(response => dispatch({
        type: LOG_IN,
        payload: response.data.token
      }))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
```

Also you need to pass `signup` function as the prop to your component:

```
const ApprovedScreen = ({signup}) => {
```

Comment: You should [use the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) rather than the function form: `const mapDispatch = {signup}`.

Comment: @markerikson was just reading about it today, but I was wondering does it work if dispatched action expects arguments?

Comment: @Clarity I tried both longhand and shorthand and neither worked. I still got the error "Can't find variable: dispatch". Additionally, passing in `{singup}` to ApprovedScreen gives me a new error that seems unrelated: "undefined is not an object" - it seems to be coming from my redux logger.

Comment: @mpc75 are you using any redux-middleware, like redux-thunk, for the async actions?

Comment: @mpc75: that's because there is no `dispatch` variable in scope in your code.  It doesn't just magically appear.  Please read through the linked documentation to understand how this works and should be used.

Comment: @Clarity good question, unfortunately, I am: `const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger))`. And I believe it's set up correctly because calling store.dispatch initially worked.

Comment: @Clarity Yes! That worked, thank you so much! And FYI, the shorthand and longhand mapdispatch funcitons both worked :)